# Norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are not $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am aware that all norms in a finite dimension vector space are equivalent regardless of how weird they are. However I am wondering what are some concrete examples of norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are not weighted $L^P$ norms? So I would like examples beyond

$$||v|| := \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i|v_i|^p \bigg)^{1/p}, \quad p\geq 1$$

Where $v = (v_1,...,v_n)^T$ and $\lambda_i > 0$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $v= (v_1,..., v_n)$ then define $|| v || = \sup_{j} |v_j| $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every norm is generated by a centrally symmetric, convex, compact set, so there is a lot.

A very nice concrete family of examples generated from any function from a wide class are Luxemburg norms. See https://regularize.wordpress.com/2018/05/24/building-norms-from-increasing-and-convex-functions-the-luxemburg-norm/

Comment: (+1) I was also about to mention the Minkowski functional. Nice link, too!

Answer (score 2):

If $v=(a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1})\in\mathbb R^n$, then let $P_v(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$. Now, consider the norms:

- $\lVert v\rVert=\sqrt{\int_0^1P_v^2(x)\,\mathrm dx}$
- $\lVert v\rVert=\max_{x\in[0,1]}\bigl\lvert P_v(x)\bigr\rvert$
- $\lVert v\rVert=\sum_{k=0}^n\bigl\lvert P_v(k)\bigr\rvert$

Comment: This is a good idea, as it just uses norms defined on the vector space of $n-1$ degree polynomials. Thanks!

Comment: Are these norms also equivalent to other norms on $R^n $?

Comment: @AkatsukiMaliki Didn't you read the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3220075/446262)? It is stated there that “all norms in a finite dimension vector space are equivalent”.

Comment: Well for a second I thought the statement was not true, because of the p-adic norm, so I thought there was an underlying assumption, but that's not on $\mathbb{R}^n$ of course

Comment: @AkatsukiMaliki The question is about norms on $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Yeah I  see that